# A "pistol" rebus

Tags: visual, rebus

Here's a rebus. I'm looking for a phrase.

[image: pistol rebus]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is the answer to this

> Fastest Gun in the West?

Comment: It's ironic how quickly you answered this.

Comment: @LordFarquaad I too was amused by the irony of the answer ;P

Comment: @LordFarquaad It's coincidence. Or even apropos. But not ironic.

Comment: @Kevin I was actually doubting myself after I sent that; I think you're right.

Comment: It's actually ironic, except using the [Alanis Morissette definition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jne9t8sHpUc)